# What's a good site to setup a support forum?

Tags: forums, forum

I have a small software company and we have a forum (WebWiz Forums) on our site.  Honestly, with all the spammer attacks, it's more hassle than it's worth.

I'd like to outsource the forum to some 3rd party site.  What's a good site to setup a forum on?

It needs to have the following qualities:

- Free
- Reliable
- Handle spam properly
- If they want to display ads, I am ok with that
- It does not necessarily need to be under my domain name.  It could be mycompany.TheForumCompany.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FreeForums.org](http://www.freeforums.org/features.php) looks pretty good.

Features include:

- Custom Admin Panel
- Over 150 different styles
- Ability to add Modules for extra functionality
- 24/7 Support
- Spam prevention
- 99.9% uptime
- Unlimited bandwidth

There is also the ability to upgrade your package:

- Host on your own domain - $15 per year
- Ad Removal - $4.95 a month
- Copyright removal - $10 per year

Comment: I set it up.  Pretty easy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's also InvisionFree forums : http://www.invisionfree.com